# There is no Configuration tools for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

**Hi everyone!**

I started to work on an old PRODUCTION server that i'm administrator on it.

The server is **Windows Server 2003** with **SQL Server 2005**.

I need to configure the SSRS on this server but I can't figure out how to reach the **Reporting Services Configuration**.

I saw on Microsoft's support site the [path of it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159644%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (*Click Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > Reporting Services Configuration*) but I don't have it on my server.

Is there are another ways of launching it ?

Thanks a lot!

#### Screen Shot of the server

[image: Screen Shot of the server]

Comment: Are you sure you have SSRS installed?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic - Yes sir!

Comment: You might try looking for the exact executable, perhaps someone removed the link in the Start menu. But this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow: very specific to your situation, and not about programming. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Windows Key + R to open "Run". Type in "RSConfigTool"

That will bring up the Reporting Services Configuration utility, provided you have SSRS installed, of course.

Raj

Comment: I know for sure that SSRS is installed on the server but i can't reach the Reporting Services Configuration. Repairing the installation can help ?